# How can i access Filename or FULL Path of selected image from gallery?

Tags: ios, xamarin

How can i access Filename or FULL Path of selected image from UIImagePickerController gallery?

---

Thank you very much for your response. but i am getting null the UIImagePickerControllerReferenceUrl.

here is my code.

```
NSUrl referenceURL = e.Info[new NSString("UIImagePickerControllerReferenceUrl")] as NSUrl;
        if (referenceURL != null) 
            Console.WriteLine("FIle path : " + referenceURL.Path.ToString ());
```

Answer (score 0):

Try using the `UIImagePickerControllerMediaURL` and `UIImagePickerControllerReferenceURL` keys. You can use those in the `UIImagePickerControllerDelegate` callback method `imagePickerController:didFinishPickingMediaWithInfo:`

Comment: You got the full path of selected image from gallery? @ ManzooPK